# Query for : How many elements of an array are matching within a string in mongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb

Suppose my JSON is like following:

```
{ "id":0,"keywords":"amount,debited,account,ticket,not,generated,now" }
{ "id":1,"keywords":"how,safe,gocash" }
{ "id":2,"keywords":"how,referral,program,gocash,works" }
```

If my array is like

```
array =["how","safe","gocash"];
```

then how do I get the count that while checking with first; count should be zero, with second three and with third two. (That means how many elements of an array are present in the string)

Is it possible or what approach I should adopt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this would require some form of modification to your schema by adding an extra field that holds the `keywords` in an array. This field becomes quite handy when running an aggregation pipeline to return the desired count of elements of an array that match the original string.

To add the additional field you would need the **[Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** operations to update the collection as follows:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    count = 0;

db.collection.find({"keywords": { "$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var keywordsArray = doc.keywords.split(',');
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "keywordsArray": keywordsArray }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (count % 100 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

The above creates an additional field `"keywordsArray"` that is a result of splitting the `keywords` string to an array.

After the operation your sample collection would have the documents:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab4"),
    "id" : 0,
    "keywords" : "amount,debited,account,ticket,not,generated,now",
    "keywordsArray" : [ 
        "amount", 
        "debited", 
        "account", 
        "ticket", 
        "not", 
        "generated", 
        "now"
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab5"),
    "id" : 1,
    "keywords" : "how,safe,gocash",
    "keywordsArray" : [ 
        "how", 
        "safe", 
        "gocash"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab6"),
    "id" : 2,
    "keywords" : "how,referral,program,gocash,works",
    "keywordsArray" : [ 
        "how", 
        "referral", 
        "program", 
        "gocash", 
        "works"
    ]
}
```

On to the next stage, the aggregation framework pipeline, run the following pipeline operation which uses the **[`$let`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/)**, **[`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** and **[`$setIntersection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** operators to work out the the desired count result:

```
var array = ["how","safe","gocash"];
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "id": 1, "keywords": 1,
            "count": {
                "$let": {
                   "vars": {
                      "commonToBoth": { "$setIntersection": [ "$keywordsArray", array ] }
                   },
                   "in": { "$size": "$$commonToBoth" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab4"),
            "id" : 0,
            "keywords" : "amount,debited,account,ticket,not,generated,now",
            "count" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab5"),
            "id" : 1,
            "keywords" : "how,safe,gocash",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e24e9ba53a16c763eaab6"),
            "id" : 2,
            "keywords" : "how,referral,program,gocash,works",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: No worries @ShvetChakra. If this has solved your problem, please consider [**accepting it as the answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) but there's no obligation in doing so.

Comment: @ShvetChakra I think you would need to create a new question for this since it's quite broad, but you can enhance your chances of getting a solution if you can include all the salient details of how you are calling the JS file and what you have tried thus far etc.

Comment: It's great :) Learned new terms in MongoDb.

Comment: sorry I did not see your comments before, I was figuring how to do it in js and now able to run the same in javascript also. Thanks again.